# Magento - price rule “buy 2 for price X” / Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

How can I make the following rule?

Product: T.Shirts comes in 5 colours and in 5 sizes. It is set up as a configurable product.

Buy one for 120.- Buy any 2 for 200.-

With buying 2, I mean not just buying 2 in color red and both in size Large. It should also work when you buy 1 red/large, 1 blue/small etc.

Is there a way to set it up without buying an extension? What I did so far:

I have added all SKUs, both for the parent and the child products, as a shipping cart rule. When I activate the rule, go and choose 2 items and press "buy", then the page stacks and never proceeds to the basket. When I deactivate the rule, then the page is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

You can only work with discounts and percentages. It is possible to add a rule like u mentioned but not with price X. U will need to work with a steady discount or percentage discount. Not sure if there extensions on magento 1.9 available for this.

Example of a price rule :

Cart price rule :
actions --> rules :
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  greater than  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Attribute Set  is  ...
Attribute Set  is  ...

I think this will need to do the job.
U fill in the 2 attributes that they need to have (the subselections)

Note : U will need to make 2 attribute sets with the colors in.

Note sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it and post back here again.